# The system does not go down

Tags: 12.04, init.d, etc

```
/etc/init.d/.depend.stop
```

My Ubuntu 12.04
The system shuts down normally not get error message
can't not open

```
 / etc / init.d / .depend.stop
    no such file of directory
```

See picture

[image: http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/21c7280b39f072361ac838005de4ab1a.png]

What can I do?

Comment: Does this file exist? Post output of 
    ls -la /etc/init.d | grep depend

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what they're for but here are three commands that will create these files and fill them with the same content as my copies of `/etc/init.d/.depend.{stop,start,boot}`

```
sudo install -b -m 644 <(<<EOF
TARGETS =
EOF) /etc/init.d/.depend.stop

sudo install -b -m 644 <(<<EOF
TARGETS =
INTERACTIVE =
EOF) /etc/init.d/.depend.start

sudo install -b -m 644 <(<<EOF
TARGETS =
INTERACTIVE =
EOF) /etc/init.d/.depend.boot
```

Comment: Ok I have created three files

{stop, start, boat}

With the same content (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

@Oli's answer should create those files for you, but if you want to shut down your system try to use:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Comment: or the powerbutton or the shut down function built in the system....

Comment: yes I just thought in this case rebooting the machine might solve his problem, but in that case `sudo reboot` would be better I guess...